# Google Analytics and FB's Like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics

Hi I need track with google analytics how much people click on FB's Like button but it doesn't work (yes I read a few tutorials and still nothing).

I have this code:

```
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {


   FB.init({
      appId: 'xxxx',
      status: false, 
      cookie: true, 
      xfbml: true
   });

  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(href, widget) {
        $.fancybox.close('#div');
        _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like']);

    }
  );

};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

GA js code is in head tag and FB js code is immediately under body tag.

Thank for your time and your answer.

Comment: which analytics are you using?  ga.js or analytics.js?  _gaq.push only works with ga.js.

Comment: I'm using analytics.js however thank you for give me direction where to look

Comment: Can you share the site?